# Angular Material Sidenav will only show first item in a nav list

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have an angular material sidenav component with a mat-nav-list in it, but it will only show the first item in the mat-nav-list. I've also tested the mat-nav-list in another context and it works as expected. Am I doing something wrong here or this some bug in angular material.

[image]

```js
navbar.ts

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name:string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```html
navbar.html

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/'"> App </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item><button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">Toggle</button></mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button mat-button aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon"
        (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>{{ name }}</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

```js
home.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.scss'
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'HealthyLivingClient';
}
```

```html
home.html

<app-navbar [name] = "name"></app-navbar>
```

If I switch the position of the mat-list-items in the mat-nav-list then I still only get the first item in the list, this time the toggle button instead.

[image]

Comment: You need to follow official documentation. there are some example for this

Comment: I started out with an example from the documentation and built on it. The documentation gives examples to be expanded upon, and my question is about why adding a simple nav list to the sidenav would only allow a single item to be added to the list or whether something specific about my code is incorrect.

Comment: Can you add your code to stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the sidenav container doesn't actually fill your browser's window by default. To do that, you have to use the `fullscreen` attribute which provides CSS styles to fit the width and height of the window:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <!-- Contents of sidenav container go here -->
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

However, it seems that the `fullscreen` CSS-only attribute is [still not documented](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9413).

Comment: This worked like a charm. So strange that like you say this isn’t documented anywhere. Cheers!